# pip install generates ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1

Tags: python, error-handling, pip, pycharm, package

I keep getting this while trying to install PyGObject for Python 3.7 in Pycharm. I at first got the error where cl.exe couldn't be found, but I did some research and would that apparently C++ toolkit was missing even though I could locate cl.exe. I reinstalled pip, toolkit, and added cl.exe to PATH, and this new error came up:

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1

Command:

```
Collecting PyGObject
Using cached PyGObject-3.36.0.tar.gz (714 kB)
Installing build dependencies: started
Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\Latitude\PycharmProjects\ESC190\project_scheduler\venv\Scripts\python.exe' 
'C:\Users\Latitude\PycharmProjects\ESC190\project_scheduler\venv\lib\site-packages\pip' install -- 
ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Latitude\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env- 
gv8msoqy\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i 
https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel pycairo
   cwd: None
Complete output (35 lines):
Collecting setuptools
Using cached setuptools-46.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (582 kB)
Collecting wheel
Using cached wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting pycairo
Using cached pycairo-1.19.1.tar.gz (205 kB)
Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, pycairo
  Running setup.py install for pycairo: started
  Running setup.py install for pycairo: finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Latitude\PycharmProjects\ESC190\project_scheduler\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u - 
  c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Latitude\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i870hprp\\pycairo\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Latitude\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i870hprp\\pycairo\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Latitude\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-si_3ert2\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\Latitude\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-gv8msoqy\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Latitude\PycharmProjects\ESC190\project_scheduler\venv\include\site\python3.7\pycairo'
       cwd: C:\Users\Latitude\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i870hprp\pycairo\
  Complete output (20 lines):
  running install
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cairo
  copying cairo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cairo
  copying cairo\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cairo
  copying cairo\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cairo
  warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

  running build_ext
  building 'cairo._cairo' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cairo
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
  Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL 
  /DNDEBUG /MT -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=19 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 - 
  IC:\Users\Latitude\PycharmProjects\ESC190\project_scheduler\venv\include -IC:\Users\Latitude\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -IC:\Users\Latitude\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tccairo/device.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cairo/device.obj
  device.c
  C:\Users\Latitude\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i870hprp\pycairo\cairo\pycairo.h(37): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cairo.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Latitude\PycharmProjects\ESC190\project_scheduler\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Latitude\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i870hprp\\pycairo\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Latitude\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i870hprp\\pycairo\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Latitude\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-si_3ert2\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\Latitude\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-gv8msoqy\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Latitude\PycharmProjects\ESC190\project_scheduler\venv\include\site\python3.7\pycairo' Check the logs for full command output.
 ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 
'C:\Users\Latitude\PycharmProjects\ESC190\project_scheduler\venv\Scripts\python.exe' 
'C:\Users\Latitude\PycharmProjects\ESC190\project_scheduler\venv\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Latitude\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-gv8msoqy\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel pycairo Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error while installing `pywhatkit`. I used `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel --user` first then installed pywhatkit using command `pip install pywhatkit` and it worked.

Comment: seems like a comment. avoid posting as answer

Answer (score -1):

delete windows temp files and add this argument to the end of the install command `--no-cache-dir`
if it didn't work try to install `tokenize` module first

Comment: by delete windows temp files do you mean from cleanup windows c drive

Comment: I meant cleaning 'C:\Windows\Temp' and 'C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp'

Comment: Now I'm getting a different error: Command "C:\Users\Latitude\PycharmProjects\ESC190\project_scheduler\venv\Scripts\python.exe c:\users\latitude\pycharmprojects\esc190\project_scheduler\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-p
y3.7.egg\pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\Latitude\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-oezi_nm8\overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary
:none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel pycairo" failed with error code 1 in None